# How can I write the regex of a 10 digit mobile number?

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a web app using Java Servlets. I have a form field that takes phone number. I am trying to validate the field for taking the phone numbers according to the indian mobile format, i.e., a 10 digit mobile number.

I have tried to use the following as the regex:

`[7-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

But I am not sure about this, as I am new at regex and this never lets the code to compile. It might have syntax error.

Anyway, I wanted to ask:

1. Is the above regex fine to validate a 10 digit mobile number?
2. Is there a better way to write the above regex for the mobile numbers of Indian format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your final question has literally nothing to do with the rest of what you posted.

Comment: is the jarfile included in your classpath? For Eclipse: "Rightclick Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries". If your libraries aren't present there the javac Compiler can't find the classes, because they aren't included

Comment: sorry for that.. I am really bad at explaining my question.. I edited the question.

Comment: yes they are included

Comment: you could use \d{10} for 10 integers which will server as mobile number if you don't want any complex rule for the mobile number part

Comment: i got an error by using \d{10}

Comment: Do you want to ask *the regex of a 10 digit phone number* or *deal with ClassNotFoundException on org.sqlite.JDBC*?

Comment: do you want me to delete one of the questions??

Comment: You can ask both, yet most of us think you either posted something wrong or have difficulties in expressing your trouble because of the way you organize your question.

Comment: okay post the answers of the first question, i'll edit the second.

Comment: Note that the `class.ForName` is no longer needed since JDBC 4.

Comment: sorry i didn't catch that.

Comment: okay thanks, removing it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems sql-jdbc jar is not found in tomcat library. You should add this jar to tomcat library than check again.

Regex of 10 digit Number

```
\\d{10}
```